# Using SQL Server stored procedures from Python (pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm have a stored procedure, code:

```
DECLARE @RC int 
DECLARE @id varchar(13) 
DECLARE @pw varchar(13) 
DECLARE @depart varchar(32) 
DECLARE @class varchar(12) 
DECLARE @name varchar(12) 
DECLARE @birthday varchar(10) 
DECLARE @grade int 
DECLARE @subgrade int 
SELECT @id = 'test' 
SELECT @pw = '12345' 
SELECT @depart = 'none' 
SELECT @class = 'GM' 
SELECT @name = 'name' 
SELECT @birthday = 'None' 
SELECT @grade = 3 
SELECT @subgrade = 2 
EXEC @RC = [my_database].[dbo].[my_table] @id, @pw, @depart, @class, @name, @birthday, @grade, @subgrade 
DECLARE @PrnLine nvarchar(4000) 
PRINT 'Stored Procedure: my_database.dbo.my_table' 
SELECT @PrnLine = ' Return Code = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @RC)
```

How i can make a raw sql query to create account using this procedure?
I'm using flask and pyodbc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [pyodbc documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/StoredProcedures)

> To call a stored procedure right now, pass the call to the execute method using either a format your database recognizes or using the [ODBC call escape format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131685.aspx). (The ODBC driver will then reformat the call for you to match the given database.)
>
> For SQL Server you would use something like this:

```
# SQL Server format
cursor.execute("exec sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')")

# ODBC format
cursor.execute("{call sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')}")
```

So to call your procedure

```
id_ = 'test' 
pw = '12345' 
depart = 'none' 
class_ = 'GM' 
name = 'name' 
birthday = 'None' 
grade = 3 
subgrade = 2 

sql = 'exec [my_database].[dbo].[my_table](?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
values = (id_, pw, depart, class_, name, birthday, grade, subgrade)

cursor.execute(sql, (values))
```

Comment: here a problem: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") 'exe my_procedure(?, ?, ?)' ('5215125', '125151', '31231')

Comment: That looks like a syntax error in the stored procedure. Is `@P1` a part of the real one?

Comment: Thank you, sql = 'exec [my_database].[dbo].[my_table] ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?' working fine(without brackets).

Comment: Without brackets works if you don't have spaces in the names, if you have spaces you need the brackets.....

Comment: Hello everybody please, How to get the return value if my stored procedure has a SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE') as ID, I want to get the ID.

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer does not address the issue of capturing the return value from the stored procedure, which can be done like this:

```python
id_ = 'test' 
pw = '12345' 
depart = 'none' 
class_ = 'GM' 
name = 'name' 
birthday = 'None' 
grade = 3 
subgrade = 2 

sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @RC int;
EXEC @RC = [my_database].[dbo].[my_sp] ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?;
SELECT @RC AS rc;
"""
values = (id_, pw, depart, class_, name, birthday, grade, subgrade)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
rc = cursor.fetchval()  # pyodbc convenience method similar to cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: this seems to cause SQL Server to recompile the query for every execution rather than reusing execution plans causing high compiles and recompiles

Comment: I tried your answer with a SP that `INSERT` records in a table. I used `pyodbc`. In that `sql` string, I had used `sql=""" SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [schema].[sp_name] ?,?,?,?,?"""  ; cur.execute( sql,values)`. The python code did not throw any error. But when I checked in the table, No data was inserted.  Why so?

Comment: @pythondumb - Did you remember to call [.commit()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit)?

Comment: Yes I did. I used conn.commit()

Comment: @pythondumb - Then please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [mcve].

Comment: Here it goes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615773/issue-in-running-sql-server-stored-proc-using-pyodbc

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget SET NOCOUNT ON in your stored procedure.

Comment: This actually helped us deal with a problem of SP not working. Still I don't see how this is a factor

Answer (score 8):

Another flavour of Gord's answer is using OUTPUT and named parameters (to be defined within the Stored procedure) for clarity.

```
id_ = 'test' 
pw = '12345' 
depart = 'none' 
class_ = 'GM' 
name = 'name' 
birthday = 'None' 
grade = 3 
subgrade = 2 

sql = """\
DECLARE @RC int;
EXEC [my_database].[dbo].[my_sp] @RC OUTPUT, @id_=?, @pw=?, @depart=?, @class_=?, @name=?, @birthday=?, @grade=?, @subgrade=?;
SELECT @RC AS rc;
"""
values = (id_, pw, depart, class_, name, birthday, grade, subgrade)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
rc = cursor.fetchval()
```

Answer (score 5):

After searching everywhere for this solution, i couldnt find a simplified version. All results seem to overcomplicate this that should be so easy to do. Heres my solution.

```
 import pyodbc
 import pandas as pd
 import datetime as d


  conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=;'
                  'Server=;'
                  'Database=;'
                  'UID=;'
                  'PWD=;')


     # define parameters to be passed in and out

     quarter_date = d.date(year=2020, month=10, day=1)

     SQL = r'exec TERRITORIES_SP @quarterStart = ' + "'" + str(quarter_date) + "'"

     print(SQL)

     try:
         cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute(SQL)
          cursor.close()
          conn.commit()
    finally:
          conn.close()
```

Comment: By using dynamic SQL you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks. What would be a better approach?

Comment: Something like `sql = r'exec TERRITORIES_SP @quarterStart = ?'` followed by `cursor.execute(sql, str(quarter_date))`. I'll admit that in this case the SQL injection risk is low, but it's still bad form to promote dynamic SQL as a "simplified" solution.

Answer (score 3):

With a cursor initialized by your connection, the sp can be called directly as follow

```
sql = " exec your_SP @codemp = ?, @fecha = ? "
prm = (dict['param1'], dict['param2'])
cursor.execute(qry, params)
```

Answer (score -6):

For MSSQL the correct format is this:

```
SQL = 'exec sp_UpdateUserGoogleAuthenticated ''?'', ''?'''
```

Try running the Stored Procedure in MSSQL in the SQL Query window and it will fail every time with () surrounding the ? marks.  If you escape the single quotes it will allow for variables with spaces in them.