# Not able to create database using stored procedure pyodbc SQL SERVER

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure that creates a Database from pyodbc

The Following is a minimal example of the code

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""\
    DECLARE @RC int
    DECLARE @ClientName varchar(255)
    SET @ClientName = 'Test'
    EXECUTE @RC = [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[sp_NAME] @ClientName
""")
conn.commit()
```

The code should ideally create a Database named '*Test*' in the SQL Server Instance. This does not produce any error. But the database is not created.

Running

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @ClientName varchar(255)
SET @ClientName = 'Test'
EXECUTE @RC = [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[sp_NAME] @ClientName
```

From SSMS seems to create the database. Already referred a couple of questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635671/using-sql-server-stored-procedures-from-python-pyodbc).

Comment: Might be worth including the DDL of your SP `sp_NAME`.

Comment: On a different note [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Try `conn.autocommit = True` immediately after opening the connection.

Comment: "From SSMS **seems** to create" - What? Either the procedure works in SSMS or it does not. The word "seems" here suggests you just don't know. So - does it work in SSMS?

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks! This works. Can you leave it as an answer with an explanation as to why `conn.autocommit = True` works when `conn.commit()` does not.

Comment: @SMor Sorry English is not my Native language. It does create the database from the SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python [DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specifies that, by default, connections should be opened with autocommit disabled. However, many databases require that DDL statements **not** be executed within a transaction. Attempts to execute DDL statements with autocommit disabled can lead to errors or unexpected results.

Therefore, it is safer to ensure that DDL statements are executed on a connection where autocommit is enabled. That can be accomplished by setting `autocommit=True` when opening the connection ...

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
```

... or by enabling `autocommit` on an existing connection ...

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
# ...
cnxn.autocommit = True
```