# CREATE PROCEDURE fails silently when called from pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am unable to create a SQL Server stored procedure using Python's pyodbc. The command executes correctly and I get no error message however the stored procedure does not appear on the server

```
import pyodbc

host = 'myServer'
database = 'model'
conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};' +
        r'SERVER=' + host + ';' +
        r'DATABASE=' + database + ';' +
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes'
    )
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """
        CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] AS 
        SELECT 1  
        """
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Try doing `conn.commit()` before closing the connection.

Comment: well that's an easy fix! feel free to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc connections default to having autocommit disabled as specified in Python's [DB API 2.0 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). In that mode, any changes to the database must be committed by calling `commit()` on the Connection.

If you want a connection with autocommit enabled, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830266/2144390) for details.