# Python PYODBC Stored procedure SQL Server - spaces on values for variable in original CSV input file - how to ecape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

[Using SQL Server stored procedures from Python (pyodbc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635671/using-sql-server-stored-procedures-from-python-pyodbc/49457235)
Following on from this thread, how do you handle spaces in variables?
e.g.

```
for CustomerID,TestCode,TestResult in csv_input:
        #query 
        query = """\
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        Declare @CustomerID nvarchar(100),
        @TestCode nvarchar(20),
        @TestResult nvarchar(10),

        exec TestData.sp_uat_TestData_Customer @CustomerID = ? , @TestCode = ?, @TestResult = ?;"""
        #set the ID as per the iteration of the loop
        args = (CustomerID,TestCode,TestResult,)
        #execute the query above using the provided variable
        cursor.execute(query,args)

        # print out the data returned by the Stored Procedure
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

In the example above @TestResult will have the value "Passed the test" in the CSV file 3rd column.

I have tried the following but with no joy:
@TestResult = '''?''', @TestResult = '?', @TestResult = [?]  and they all give pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

I even tried adding single quotes to the value in the input CSV and still no progress.
Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Spaces in the literals should not be an issue. Please post exact error from code you posted where qmarks do not have punctuation and not your attempts.

Comment: That comma after ` nvarchar(10)` looks wrong.

Comment: @GordThompson it is, I removed some params to make it simpler and forgot to remove that comma.

Comment: In the stored procedure definition is `@TestResult` declared as an OUTPUT parameter by chance?

Comment: OK, figured it out. the values in the CSV file were in UTF-8 encoding and the values in the Stored Procedure are in Ansi format. when the 2 strings were compared they were different.