# Get the output of a stored procedure from Pyodbc using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from Python, but when I run it, I can not get the output form the cursor.

```
import pyodbc
import math
import requests
import pandas as pd
cnx  = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;UID=xxxxx;PWD=Minonja')

SQL_send_data="""

DECLARE 
              @messageStatus nvarchar(200)

SELECT @messageStatus = N'@messageStatus'

EXEC   [cvm].[CVMSendSms_sp]
              @userId = N'PT180209.1100.628362',
              @codeSms = 79,
              @messageStatus = @messageStatus OUTPUT,
              @date = '',
              @amount = N'0'

SELECT convert(varchar,@messageStatus) as reponse


"""
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL_send_data)
cursor.fetchval()  
print(cursor)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I get the error below:

> ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query.

Please help! I tried a lot to ways but I'm not able to fix this error

Comment: Just a guess but try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the start of your SQL just after the `DECLARE ...` before the first `SELECT ...`.

Comment: Hello, you have a typo `cursor.fetchval()` should be `cursor.fetchall()` and try setting it in a variable like this: `c = cursor.fetchall()` and then `print(c)`. Btw is the soterd procedure in the database itself or you are writing it with python? Because that is not how you execute a procedure with `pyodbc`

Comment: It tried both but I got the same error.

Comment: Yes because that is not a valid query. Like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635671/using-sql-server-stored-procedures-from-python-pyodbc) the way you are calling the procedure is not right.

Comment: Once you sort out the Python side of things... `SELECT convert(varchar,@messageStatus) as reponse` is likely to give you a 1 character response because it's equivalent to `SELECT convert(varchar(1),@messageStatus) as reponse`