# Issue in running SQL Server Stored Proc using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I am trying to run an Stored Proc in SQL Server (Synapse) using `pyodbc`.This SP merely performs `INSERT` operation into a table.

```
sql =""" EXEC my_sp (?,?,?)"""
values = (str(v1),str(v2),int(v3))
cur.execute(sql,(values))
conn.commit()
```

This above code is not giving any error. But when I am querying the Table, I don't see the records. However, when I am running above SP in SSMS console, this works fine.

Can't figure out why this is so?

Any clue?

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, try using `conn = pyodbc.connect( … , autocommit=True)` and commenting out the  `conn.commit()`

Comment: I'm facing same issue. No data is being inserted to db, event after `autocommit=True`. However, output variable is being returned or if there is any select query. it seems only one statement is being executed.